# remove numbers from beginning of a line in a string with PHP

Tags: php, split

I have a bunch of strings in php that all look like this:

```
10 NE HARRISBURG
4 E HASWELL
2 SE OAKLEY
6 SE REDBIRD
PROVO
6 W EADS
21 N HARRISON
```

What I am needing to do is remove the numbers and the letters from before the city names. The problem I am having is that it varies a lot from city to city. The data is almost never the same. Is it possible to remove this data and keep it in a separate string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the following works for you:

```
$new_str = preg_replace('/^([0-9]* \w+ )?(.*)$/', '$2', $str);
```

Answer (score 7):

Check out regular expressions and [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). `$nameOfCity = preg_replace("/^\d+\s+\w{1,2}\s+/", "", $source);`

Explained:

1. `^` matches the beginning of the string
2. `\d+\s+` start with one or more numbers followed by one or more white-space characters
3. `\w{1,2}\s+` then there should be one or two letters followed by one or more white-space characters
4. The rest of the string should be the name of the city.

Cases not covered

- If there's only the text qualifier before the city name
- If there's only a number qualifier before the city name
- If there's only a number qualifier and a the cities name is two letters long.

If you want to be more precise, I assume you could enumerate all the possible letters before the city name `(S|SE|E|NE|N|NW|W|SW)` instead of matching any one or two letter long strings.

Answer (score 1):

For each line, try this :

```
$arr = preg_split('/ /', $line);

if(count($arr) === 3)
{
    // $arr[0] is the number
    // $arr[1] is the letter
    // $arr[2] is your city
}
else
{
    // Like "PROVO" no number, no letter
}
```

Yes, this code is horible but it works... And it keeps all your data.
The important thing is to use `preg_split` not the deprecated `split` method.

Comment: Wouldn't preg_match be a better fit? Especially if the city name contains two or more words e.g. New York, San Marino, Frankfurt af Main

Comment: Given that you're splitting on a non-regular expression, you can use `explode()`. However, the above fails for cities with multiple words such as New York and Sun Valley.

Comment: Yes... `explode()` should work fine with $limit = 3 according to the [explode doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a list of cities as an array, try:

```
if(preg_match_all("/(\w+$)/", $source, $_matches)) {
  $cities = $_matches[1];
}
```

Comment: Same as William Durands solution, this doesn't not match cities that have a name that contains more than one word. The expression must contain the unwanted parts as well though with a zero or one qualifier. Furthermore, preg_match_all is a bit unnecessary as there is only one possible match. Doesn't hurt though.